# SSISDB - Create Catalog Greyed out

Tags: sql-server

We are in the process of migrating our dbs from SQL 2016 to SQL 2019.  I was having issues restoring the SSISDB on a dev server so decided to start fresh and deploy packages on new server instead.  I deleted SSISDB, cleaned up job, and restarted services.  I don't have the option to Create the Catalog now.  Any ideas?

[image]

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'SSISDB'
GO
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [SSISDB]    Script Date: 3/27/2023 1:35:55 PM ******/
DROP DATABASE [SSISDB]
GO
USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [SSIS Server Maintenance Job]    Script Date: 3/27/2023 1:45:30 PM ******/
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_id=N'b5d21d88-2f64-4474-ac44-9c0cad5f9173', @delete_unused_schedule=1
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be that SSIS is not installed.

> You can launch SQL Server Discovery Report – Determining what SQL
> Server Components are Installed
>
> Location on the hard drive: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start
> Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2017\Configuration Tools
>
> Good link on the subject:
> sql-server-2012-discovery-report-determining-what-sql-server-components-are-installed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/287350/create-catalog-is-greyed-out-in-ssis

Comment: Aha!  It appears it was not setup correctly.  Thank you Peter!

Comment: Welcome, don't forget to mark the Answer as answered so people know it is verified :)